# Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:3306: bind: address already in use

Tags: php, apache, docker, laravel-5, docker-compose

I have to make `Laravel` app and to deliver a Dockerfile, but I'm really stuck with this. Before that I had a nightmare wile installing `laravel` on my machine.

I'm trying to get `dockervel` image and following the steps here:
http://www.spiralout.eu/2015/12/dockervel-laravel-development.html

But when I run dartisan make:auth it gives this error below:

```
**ERROR:** for dockervel_mysql_1  **Cannot restart container** c258b418c03cbd6ec02c349c12cf09403f0eaf42fa9248019af7860d037d6474: **driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint dockervel_mysql_1** (da3dd576458aa1fe3af7b539c48b9d61d97432cf5e9ee02d78562851f53981ae): E**rror starting userland proxy: listen tcp0.0.0.0:3306: bind: address already in use.**
```

I have tried to Change the default port in the `docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
   ports:
     - "8084:80"
```

Still nothing, also tried to stop apache2 (`service apache2 stop`) on my machine ,also tried `docker-compose restart` and removing docker container  `dockervel_mysql_1`.

I have to mention that I have already one `Laravel proj.` in `/var/www/laravel`.

***Please help!***

Comment: From the output of `sudo netstat -antp` what is using port 3306?

Comment: I got this  , I assume that is my local mysql . Three days ago I installed laravel  and mysql using this http://tecadmin.net/install-laravel-framework-on-ubuntu/#. Thank you very much for your help!

tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1370/mysqld

Comment: goodnesskay answer helped me.
But for me the command was: sudo service mysql stop

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Probably you have already a MySQL service running in port 3306. You should close it first.
Then try to end `docker-compose down` and restart it with `docker-compose up`.
Remember also to change the permissions after you add a file in your project (like `dartisan make:auth`) with `dpermit`

*UPDATE:*
since you have changed the port to "8084" you should go to `localhost:8084`
If you see the apache default then you probably are browsing another server since dockervel is build upon `nginx`.
You have also probably have some gaps on Docker. Don't mix your local storage with docker storage. `/var/www` in a container is different than your local `/var/www`. in docker-compose.yml you mount the local `~/dockervel/www` to containers `/var/www`.
I would suggest that you start all over again and revert the changes you've made to your apache server. Shut it down, you don't need it. Dockervel will provide you with an NginX server in a container.

Comment: Look at my new comment below !I answered.

Comment: We should have solution which support local mysql, stopping local mysql can not be solution.

Comment: @AdarshRajput in this case you should not start mysql from container and link the other services with your local mysql. Or at least use another port for one of them. You cannot have two services using the same port.

Comment: @SpiralOut- You are right (technically). BUT here you should tell how to use different port in docker OR local mysql + might be OP's docker setup is duplicate & have no local instance. See the main issue from OP: [have tried to Change the default port in the docker-compose.yml] || still 3306 in use, means OP might be doing setting at wrong place.

Comment: @AdarshRajput you are also right, this might be another way to handle this, but then again it should not be on `nginx's` port but `mysql's` port. If you tested it and it works for you then upvote [@cece answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63711149/6490721) bellow

Answer (score 97):

I had the same problem and

```
sudo netstat -nlpt |grep 3306
```

showed me the PID and which service it was started by (mysgld). Whenever I tried to kill the PID then it was started again. But the problem was fixed when I stopped the service by

```
sudo service mysql stop
```

Notice that you will have to use `mysql` and not `mysqld`.

I hope that this will do it for you - I was able to run `docker-compose up` without any problems

Comment: We should have solution which support local mysql, stopping local mysql can not be solution. Guiding new comers to wrong thing.

Comment: got this error running this: `netstat: t: unknown or uninstrumented protocol`

Comment: Great, this is what solved me the problem. There is any way to avoid mysql service start on boot?

Answer (score 55):

Try to kill all the processes using the port `3306`:

```
sudo kill `sudo lsof -t -i:3306`
```

Then, run your docker containers:

```
sudo docker-compose up
```

Comment: This brutal way works for me!

Answer (score 30):

My fix for this issue was to go into

> docker-compose.yml

and change
`ports: -3306:3306` to `ports: -3307:3306`
then run this command again:

```
docker-compose up
```

Comment: So underrated answer, however this is the good way when you want to use it beside an another mysql service.

Comment: I would vote for this one as it allow coexistence of multiple mysql service/instances, get the current issue solved won't affect anything else especially those unknow things.

Answer (score 19):

On Ubuntu, running this command will stop your mysql from running for your docker container to work:

```
sudo service mysql stop
```

Then, if your apache2 is running, you need to stop the service especially when you want to work with nginx:

```
sudo service apache2 stop
```

Then, you can run your `docker-compose up -d ...` command

Comment: This is the current easy solution

Comment: We should have solution which support local mysql, stopping local mysql can not be solution

Answer (score 6):

**First Solution :**

```
  sudo service mysql stop
```

and then run

```
 docker-compose up
```

to start the application , It is an quick and fast solution to run this mysql stop command to stop the current MySQL service on port 3306 port so the same port can be available for your docker application.

Scenario 1 : Problem will come when you want to run both application one which was running previously and next you want to run now at this time it won't work.

**Second Solution to Scenario 1:**

If your next/current application coming from docker then try below it will work without disturbing first application mysql service of 3306 port

> Open and changed the MySQL port from docker-compose.yml file

Default configuration

```
ports:
      - ${SERVER_PORT_DB:-3306}:3306
```

changed port

```
 ports:
      - ${SERVER_PORT_DB:-3307}:3306
```

and now run below command to start the application

```
docker-composer up
```

Answer (score 5):

So for me when I was trying to load and run MySQL image in docker container, I was getting the same error:
[image]

And even after stopping local mysql server in system preferences didn't help:
[image]
Cause the port 3306 was used by my tomcat server, so basically you have to make sure the **port** (in this case 3306) that the docker command wants to use should not be in use by any other service otherwise the command will fail

Answer (score 3):

**This** option did it for me:

`sudo pkill mysql`

Answer (score 2):

The error you are seeing is from a local mysql instance listening on port 3306 (currently on pid 1370 from your comments). You won't be able to run a container that publishes on this host port while it's already in use by another process. Solutions are to either stop mysql on the local host, or to change/remove the published port in your container. If the port is only needed by other containers, you can leave it unpublished and they can communicate directly on the docker private network (by default, this is "bridge").

Comment: $service mysqld stop
gives me this :
$mysqld: unrecognized service
About the second solution is it complicated as it sounds?

Comment: You can probably do an `ls /etc/init.d` to find the service name for mysql. Changing the mysql published port is the same steps you changed for port 80, you just need to do this for 3306 instead of 80.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the mysql port
because you are installing mysql on your machine and it takes the default port 3306

and now you are trying to make dockervel_mysql_1 run to the same port 3306 , this is why you see in the error "Address already in use"

so if you change dockervel_mysql_1 port to 3307 for example it will works fine , without stopping the mysql that is running on you machine

Answer (score 0):

Running this command **fixed the issue for me:**

`docker swarm leave --force`

**Explanation:**
I had started docker swarm service as a master node in my localhost. 
Swarm was taking network priority and making use of this ports already

Answer (score 0):

If tomcat is running on your machine which is connected to MySQL 3306 port then check by killing the tomcat first and then trying to do docker-compose up.

I used two different versions of MySQL, MySQL 5 on my local machine and 8 on docker. So when your connected to mysql5 on 3306 in tomcat and if you just stop the mysql5, then the process isn't completed yet since tomcat is still connected to 3306. Kill the tomcat and then up the docker it should work.

Happy coding!!

Answer (score 0):

I know this question has been quite old but someone still looking for answers. You don't have to run any kill command instead you can use docker `--remove-orphans` flag and it will clean it up for you. For example

```
docker-compose up -d --build --remove-orphans
```

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me, just changed the app's port to `8084:80`, like described [here](http://%20https://irawan.id.au/php-ramework/Laravel/install.html).