# Laravel not working showing Apache default page on localhost. Virtual Host changes failed

Tags: php, apache, laravel, docker, virtualhost

I have to make LAravel app and to deliver a Dockerfile ,but i'm realy stuck with this. Before that I had a nightmare wile installing laravel on my machine.

I'm trying to get dockervel image and I'm following the steps here: http://www.spiralout.eu/2015/12/dockervel-laravel-development.html

I had **problems before** and made changes :[Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp0.0.0.0:3306: bind: address already in use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37896369/error-starting-userland-proxy-listen-tcp0-0-0-03306-bind-address-already-in/37933441#37933441)

All good till the step

> fix permissions: **dpermit** Now you have a registration system active. **Go
>   to localhost** and register a new user to see that db's are running ok.

When I go to localhost I get : Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page
https://assets.digitalocean.com/articles/lamp_1404/default_apache.png

I have catched this : when I run

```
$ dcomposer-create
It gets to the end but I get this 
Warning: This development build of composer is over 60 days old. It is recommended to update it by running "/usr/bin/composer self-update" to get the latest version.
Installing laravel/laravel (v5.2.31)
  - Installing laravel/laravel (v5.2.31)
    Downloading: 100%         

Created project in /var/www
> php -r "copy('.env.example', '.env');"
```

*Shoud I move on eith installation or first fix this?*

I **alredy have** a laravel project in **var/www/laravel** (on local laravel environment).
And my etc/hosts file looks like :

```
127.0.0.1   laravel.example.com
127.0.1.1   me-Lenovo-Z50-75

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
127.0.0.1  laravel.example.com
```

And **$ dcomposer-create**  creates  application in **dockervel/www/** .

I have changeg now made **dockervel.example.com.conf in /etc/apache2/sites-available**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerName dockervel.example.com
        DocumentRoot /home/me/Desktop/dockerlaravel/dockervel/www/public
        DirectoryIndex index.php

        <Directory /home/me/Desktop/dockerlaravel/dockervel/www>
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory >
        <Directory >
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And changed /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1  dockervel.example.com
127.0.1.1   me-Lenovo-Z50-75

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
127.0.0.1  dockervel.example.com
```

I also run:

```
$ a2ensite dockervel.example.com
$ sudo service apache2 reload
```

And When I run :

```
apachectl -S
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server 127.0.1.1 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost 127.0.1.1 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost dockervel.example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/dockervel.example.com.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost laravel.example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/laravel.example.com.conf:1)
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/var/lock/apache2" mechanism=fcntl 
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33
Group: name="www-data" id=33
```

And when I continue with the instalation

```
$ dnodejs nmp install - this is ok 
$ dnodejs gulp install
[17:40:09] Using gulpfile /var/www/gulpfile.js
[17:40:09] Task 'install' is not in your gulpfile
[17:40:09] Please check the documentation for proper gulpfile formatting
```

*As you can see ,All **goes in /var/www** but I want it to be in my working directory  **/home/me/Desktop/dockerlaravel/dockervel** .*

*I can not see what is the problem is the problem?*

Comment: This is a question for http://serverfault.com/

Comment: in addition `</Directory /home/me/Desktop/dockerlaravel/dockervel/www><Directory >` you put your directory on the previous closing tag here move it down a line

Comment: Ok,  I moved it,still nothing. I will post it there too , thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have changed the port to "8084" you should go to localhost:8084
If you see the apache default then you probably are browsing another server since dockervel is build upon nginx.
You have also probably have some gaps on Docker. Don't mix your local storage with docker storage. /var/www in a container is different than your local /var/www. in docker-compose.yml you mount the local ~/dockervel/www to containers /var/www.
I would suggest that you start all over again and revert the changes you've made to your apache server. Shut it down, you don't need it. Dockervel will provide you with an NginX server in a container.

Comment: I stopped mysql and apache with 
echo "manual" >> /etc/init/mysql.override

update-rc.d -f apache2 remove
And started allover again without seting docker.yml port to 8084 ,but after  dup on localhost I get
404 Not Found

nginx/1.8.1
and on localhost:8000
This site can’t be reached

localhost refused to connect . :/

Comment: Well done. Now run `dcomposer-create` and then `dpermit`

Comment: It went ok! Only can't register showing error :QueryException in Connection.php line 713:
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'homestead.users' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `users` where `email` = something@somethin.com limit 1)
......
And still this error :

dnodejs gulp install
[19:53:26] Using gulpfile /var/www/gulpfile.js
[19:53:26] Task 'install' is not in your gulpfile
[19:53:26] Please check the documentation for proper gulpfile formatting

Comment: Works :             php artisan serve (it shows the laravel app on localhost:8000)
            , php artisan make:controller ,dartisan make:controller 
Doesn't work:         dartisan serve (site can't be reached)        ,  php artisan migrate (beacuse there is no mysql).
I don't care about php artisan commands ,I'm worried about the dartisan serve !

Comment: you don't need `serve` to run. After each file addition (like make:cotroller)  you have to run `dpermit`