# Docker Error bind: address already in use

Tags: ubuntu, docker, ubuntu-14.04, bind, docker-compose

When I run `docker-compose up` in my Docker project it fails with the following message:

> Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:3000: bind: address already in use

```
netstat -pna | grep 3000
```

shows this:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
```

I've already tried `docker-compose down`, but it doesn't help.

Comment: Run a `sudo netstat -pna | grep 3000` to get the process that's listening.

Comment: Your output shows some other process is listening on port 3000 already. Can you use some other port? Try with `sudo` to see the process name.

Comment: Yep, there was ntop on this port. Thanx! I didn't know `sudo` can change output :)

Comment: For me it's port 8888 which is docker proxy

Comment: I fixed this same issue in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58772307/3530707

Answer (score 205, accepted):

In your case it was some other process that was using the port and as indicated in the comments, `sudo netstat -pna | grep 3000` helped you in solving the problem.

While in other cases (I myself encountered it many times) it mostly is the same container running at some other instance. In that case `docker ps` was very helpful as often I left the same containers running in other directories and then tried running again at other places, where same container names were used.

**How `docker ps` helped me:**

> `docker rm -f $(docker ps -aq)` is a short command which I use to remove all containers.

**Edit:** Added how `docker ps` helped me.

Comment: Actually, I have this problem often. And nothing, but `docker-compose down` helps

Comment: That is sure to help, on the condition that you are running it in the same directory where you ran `docker-compose up`. While I recommend in my answer to find the container which is already running and take desired action. I felt appropriate to remove them, if someone does not want to remove, then there's instead using `rm` use `stop` to stop them.

Comment: I have another server running on the same port that `tensorflow/tensorflow` image are will run. How can I setup my image to run in another port. I've tried this:

`docker run -it -d -p 8888:8000 tensorflow/tensorflow`

I binded port 8888 from my image to 8000 on client, but don't work.

Comment: @EmanuelFontelles When trying to debug, do not use `-d` option. Now, ports are exposed as `HOST:CONTAINER`. Thus you should run `docker run -it -p 8000:8888`

Comment: those who runs on ubuntu willl want to add sudo between each call to docker:
`sudo docker rm -f $(sudo docker ps -aq)`

Comment: `docker rm -f $(docker ps -aq)` solved the problem, thanks !

Answer (score 260):

This helped me:

```sh
docker-compose down  # Stop container on current dir if there is a docker-compose.yml
docker rm -fv $(docker ps -aq)  # Remove all containers
sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep <port number>  # List who's using the port
```

and then:
`kill -9 <process id>` (macOS) or `sudo kill <process id>` (Linux).

Source: [comment by user Rub21](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4950#issuecomment-398879461).

Comment: `docker rm -fv $(docker ps -aq)` this line was all I needed.  Thanks

Comment: lsof worked a charm, killed the process and back in action....

Comment: Interestingly, each time I kill, it assigned to another port that I find very wired.

Comment: `sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep <port number>` -> this one was good enough to debug on OSX ty :)

Comment: For macOS the last step should be google that process first =) 
This is my case https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/682332

Comment: to add to this: my mistake was having apache2 already listening on the port i wanted

Comment: You can also do `lsof -i :<port number>` as a shortcut

Comment: what is the command in windows to list who is using port?

Comment: Thanks ! really helped me.
especially : sudo lsof -i -P -n

Answer (score 85):

I had the same problem. I fixed this by stopping the Apache2 service on my host.

Comment: this was my problem too, I forgot I installed Apache

Comment: FR: To stop Apache 2 web server, enter: # /etc/init.d/apache2 stop

Comment: `sudo service apache2 stop && sudo service nginx stop` worked for me.

Comment: somehow apache was enabled after an update/restart. it was listening on port 80 and impeding an important container from running.

Comment: Apache2 came on my machine with installation of PHP8. The problem occured after reboot, when apache2 was auto started on system start. As I don't need it locally on my computer I just removed it via `sudo apt remove apache2`.

Comment: nice, thx! This was the right fix.

Answer (score 68):

You can kill the process listening on that port easily with one command below :

```
kill -9 $(lsof -t -i tcp:<port#>)
```

ex :

> `kill -9 $(lsof -t -i tcp:<port#>)`

or for ubuntu:

> `` sudo kill -9 `sudo lsof -t -i:8000` ``

Man page for lsof : https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/lsof.8.html

-9 is for hard kill without checking any deps.

---

(Not related, but might be useful if its PORT 5000 mystery) - the culprit process is due to Mac OS monterery.

The port 5000 is commonly used to serve local development servers. When updating to the latest macOS operating system, I was unable the docker to bind to port 5000, because it was already in use. (You may find a message along the lines of Port 5000 already in use.)

By running lsof -i :5000, I found out the process using the port was named **ControlCenter**, which is a native macOS application. If this is happening to you, even if you use brute force (and kill) the application, it will restart itself. In my laptop, lsof -i :5000 returns that Control Center is being used by process id 433. I could do killall -p 433, but macOS keeps restarting the process.

The process running on this port turns out to be an AirPlay server. You can deactivate it in

**System Preferences › Sharing, and unchecking AirPlay Receiver to release port 5000.**

Comment: the best answer for Mac users including M1 chips like my case.

Comment: Wow, great catch on the 5000!

Comment: Thanks it works!
- sudo kill -9 `sudo lsof -t -i:8080`

Answer (score 24):

I had same problem,
`docker-compose down --rmi all` (in the same directory where you run docker-compose up)
helps

UPD: CAUTION - this will also delete the local docker images you've pulled (from [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37971961/docker-error-bind-address-already-in-use/55139407#comment109359288_55139407))

Comment: Yes, it always helps, but `down` is the last thing you usually want to do. Losing the current state is not a piece of sugar.

Comment: This will also delete the local docker images you've pulled so use it with caution

Comment: You should have mentioned it will delete the local docker images in the answer.

Answer (score 23):

For Linux/Unix:

Simple search for linux utility using following command

```
netstat -nlp | grep 8888
```

It'll show processing running at this port, then kill that process using PID (look for a PID in row) of that process.

```
kill PID
```

Comment: netstat shows the PID/program(e.g. 2714/splunkd).sudo kill 2714 works. Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

In some cases it is critical to perform a more in-depth debugging to the problem before stopping a container or killing a process.

Consider following the checklist below:

1) **Check you current docker compose environment** 
 Run `docker-compose ps`.
 If port is in use by another container, stop it with `docker-compose stop <service-name-in-compose-file>` or remove it by replacing `stop` with `rm`.

2) **Check the containers running outside your current workspace** 
Run `docker ps` to see list of all containers running under your host.
If you find the port is in use by another container, you can stop it with `docker stop <container-id>`. 
(*) Because you're not under the scope of the origin `compose` environment - it is a good practice first to use [docker inspect](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/inspect/) to gather more information about the container that you're about to stop.

3) **Check if port is used by other processes running on the host**
For example if the port is 6379 run:

```
$ sudo netstat -ltnp | grep ':6379'
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      915/redis-server 12 
tcp6       0      0 ::1:6379                :::*                    LISTEN      915/redis-server 12
```

(*)  You can also use the [lsof](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/lsof.8.html) command which is mainly used to retrieve information about files that are opened by various processes (I suggest running `netstat` before that).

So, In case of the output above the `PID` is `915`. Now you can run:

```
$ ps j 915
 PPID   PID  PGID   SID TTY      TPGID STAT   UID   TIME COMMAND
    1   915   915   915 ?           -1 Ssl    123   0:11 /usr/bin/redis-server 127.0.0.1:6379
```

And see the ID of the parent process (`PPID`) and the execution command.
You can also run: `$ pstree -s <PID>` to a visual display of the process and its related processes.

In our case we can see that the process probably is a daemon (PPID is 1) - In that case consider running: 
 A) `$ cat /proc/<PID>/status` in order to get a more in-depth information about the process like the number of threads spawned by the process, its capabilities, etc'.
B) `$ systemctl status <PID>` in order to see the [systemd](/questions/tagged/systemd) unit that caused the creation of a specific process. If the service is not critical - you can [stop and disable the service](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-systemctl-to-manage-systemd-services-and-units).

4) **Restart Docker service** 
Run: `sudo service docker restart`.

5) **You reached this point and..** 
Only if its not placing your system at risk - consider restarting the server.

Answer (score 12):

I had apache running on my ubuntu machine. I used this command to kill it!

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop
```

Comment: I had the same issue, but I used "sudo service apache2 stop" to solve the problem.

Answer (score 11):

Most probably this is because you are already running a web server on your host OS, so it conflicts with the web server that Docker is attempting to start.

So try this one-liner before trying anything else:

`sudo service apache2 stop; sudo service nginx stop; sudo nginx -s stop;`

Comment: This works for me, but then I can't restart apache2 correctly, when the docker container is running

Comment: @r34 This is expected behavior. You can run apache2 either on host OS or via Docker, not both of them simultaneously.

Comment: another one to try `sudo httpd -k stop` as my php switching script re-started apache for me...

Comment: Thanks, in my case it was `sudo service redis stop`

Answer (score 9):

In my case it was

> Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:9000: bind: address already in use

And all that I need is turn off debug listening in php storm [image: icon]

Comment: PhpStorm was the culprit

Answer (score 9):

If redis server is started as a service, it will restart itself when you using `kill -9 <process_id>` or `` sudo kill -9 `sudo lsof -t -i:<port_number>` `` . In that case you will need to stop the redis service using following command.

`sudo service redis-server stop`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 7):

I was getting the below error when i was trying to launch a new container -

`listen tcp 0.0.0.0:8080: bind: address already in use.`

To check which process is running on port `8080`, run below command:

`netstat -tulnp | grep 8080`

i got the output below

`[root@ip-112-x6x-2x-xxx.xxxxx.compute.internal (aws_main) ~]# netstat -tulnp | grep 8080 tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:* LISTEN      **12749**/java [root@ip-112-x6x-2x-xxx.xxxxx.compute.internal (aws_main) ~]#`

run

`kill -9 12749`

Then try to relaunch the container it should work

Comment: Spot on ! your solution helped .

Answer (score 5):

Check `docker-compose.yml`, it might be the case that the port is specified twice.

```
version: '3'
services:
  registry:
    image: mysql:5.7
        ports:
      - "3306:3306"             <--- remove either this line or next
      - "127.0.0.1:3306:3306"
```

Comment: This one worked for me, I happened to be repeating the ports in my docker-compose.yml

Answer (score 4):

Here's yet another answer because it's the only thing that worked for me.

REFERNENCE: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61888620/2027793

I ran this and kept seeing 3 php-fpm services running and listening on port 9000

```
sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep 9000
```

If then tried killing all the services, which kept restarting themselves automatically...

```
sudo kill -9 <process_id>
sudo pkill <process_name>
```

I decided that since I couldn't kill the beast, I might as well play along with it and figure out how to change the port it was using, which is where I stumbled on the answer referenced above. You find the directory where your php is running.

```
cd /usr/local/etc/php/<php_version#>/php-fpm.d/
```

Edit the config file

```
vi www.conf
```

Find the line with this and change the port number

```
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
```

Now repeat the find and kill actions above and then proceed to get your docker containers starting up again like they should.

Answer (score 3):

I upgraded my docker this afternoon and ran into the same problem. I tried restarting docker but no luck.

Finally, I had to restart my computer and it worked. Definitely a bug.

Comment: Restarting helped for me too. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue several times. Restarting docker seems to do the trick

Comment: i see how to restart a container. How to restart docker?

Comment: `sudo systemctl restart docker `, had the same problem after installing firewalld

Answer (score 2):

A variation of @DmitrySandalov's answer: I had tomcat/java running on 8080, which needed to keep going. Looked at the docker-compose.yml file and altered the entry for 8080 to another of my choosing.

```
nginx:
  build: nginx
  ports:
    #- '8080:80' <-- original entry
    - '8880:80'
    - '8443:443'
```

Worked perfectly. (The only wrinkle is the change will be wiped if I ever update the project, since it's coming from an external repo.)

Comment: make sure comment or remove that line of code that  used port, if not it will keep trying use that port.

Answer (score 2):

Changing network_mode: "bridge" to "host" did it for me.

This with

```
version: '2.2'
services:
  bind:
    image: sameersbn/bind:latest
    dns: 127.0.0.1
    ports:
      - 172.17.42.1:53:53/udp
      - 172.17.42.1:10000:10000
    volumes:
        - "/srv/docker/bind:/data"
    environment:
      - 'ROOT_PASSWORD=secret'
    network_mode: "host"
```

Answer (score 2):

At first, make sure [which service you are running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198/how-can-you-find-out-which-process-is-listening-on-a-tcp-or-udp-port-on-windows) in your specific port. In your case, you are already using port number 3000.

```
netstat -aof | findstr :3000
```

now [stop that process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11583562/how-to-kill-a-process-running-on-particular-port-in-linux) which is running on specific port

```
lsof -i tcp:3000
```

Answer (score 1):

I resolve the issue by restarting Docker.

Answer (score 1):

Just a side note if you have the same issue and is with Windows:

In my case the process in my way is just `grafana-server.exe`. Because I first downloaded the binary version and double click the executable, and it now starts as a service by user `SYSTEM` which I cannot `taskkill` (no permission)

I have to go to "Service manager" of Windows and search for service "Grafana", and stop it. After that port 3000 is no longer occupied.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This helps me, even in my system Grafana was running so I had to uninstall it. Then docker-compose up works perfectly. Thanks @WesternGun. I almost searched 2 days for this issue.

Answer (score 1):

It makes more sense to change the port of the docker update instead of shutting down other services that use port 80.

[image: change to port in docker browser]

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the issue was that I was running the MongoDB as a root user, and stopping that did the trick.

```
sudo brew services stop mongodb-community
```

Answer (score 1):

For **Windows** users. This advice from [official docker GitHub](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/9272#issuecomment-776225866) helped me.

```
net stop winnat
docker-compose up ...
net start winnat
```

Answer (score 0):

The one that was using the port 8888 was Jupiter and I had to change the configuration file of Jupiter notebook to run on another port.

to list who is using that specific port.
sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep 9

You can specify the port you want Jupyter to run uncommenting/editing the following line in ~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py:

## c.NotebookApp.port = 9999

In case you don't have a jupyter_notebook_config.py try running jupyter notebook --generate-config. See this for further details on Jupyter configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Before it was running on :docker run -d --name oracle -p 1521:1521 -p 5500:5500 qa/oracle
I just changed the port to docker run -d --name oracle -p 1522:1522 -p 5500:5500 qa/oracle

it worked fine for me !

Answer (score 0):

On my machine a PID was not being shown from this command `netstat -tulpn` for the in-use port (8080), so i could not kill it, killing the containers and restarting the computer did not work. So `service docker restart` command restarted docker for me (ubuntu) and the port was no longer in use and i am a happy chap and off to lunch.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it is too rude, but works for me. restart docker service itself

```
sudo service docker restart
```

hope it works for you also!

Answer (score 0):

I have run the container with another port, like... 8082 :-)

Answer (score 0):

I came across this problem. My simple solution is to remove the mongodb from the system

Commands to remove mongodb in Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get purge mongodb mongodb-clients mongodb-server mongodb-dev

sudo apt-get purge mongodb-10gen 

sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me add one more case, because I had the same error and none of the solutions listed so far works:

```
serv1:
  ...
  networks:
  privnet:
    ipv4_address: 10.10.100.2
  ...

serv2:
  ...
  # no IP assignment, no dependencies
  
networks:
  privnet:
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 10.10.100.0/24
```

depending on the init order, serv2 may get assigned the IP 10.10.100.2 before serv1 is started, so I just assign IPs manually for all containers to avoid the error. Maybe there are other more elegant ways.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and by stopping `docker container` it was resolved.

```
sudo docker container stop <container-name>
```

Answer (score 0):

i solved with this `sudo service redis-server stop`

Comment: So did this person: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59797983/4294399

Answer (score 0):

I tried all, including disabling the airplay one nothing worked.

In the end, the simple solution worked.
in app run defined host as 0.0.0.0 and port 5000 explicitly , and bing everything worked

```
app.run(debug=True,host="0.0.0.0",port=5000)
```

Now run the app as

```
docker run -p 5000:5000 <Image Name>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, using Linux Ubuntu 22, the problem was that exists another container running under root user.

So I did it bellow:

```
// Stop all running containers of standard user
docker stop $(docker ps -aq)

// Change to root user
sudo -i

// Stop all running containers of root user
docker stop $(docker ps -aq)

// Back to your standard user
exit
```

After that I released Redis port 6379, and I could run again my project and everything went well.

Answer (score 0):

You have to stop that service that is using that port with

```
systemctl stop
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with Laravel Sail in Windows WSL Ubuntu and finally fixed with the below commands:

First, run Windows PowerShell as administrator then enter below commands one by one:

```
net stop winnat
netsh int ipv4 set dynamic tcp start=49152 num=16384
netsh int ipv6 set dynamic tcp start=49152 num=16384
net start winnat
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case Grafana Server was running in my Windows system because of which port was occupied. So I had to uninstall the Grafana server from the system and rest worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Something that just started happening to me without changing my docker config, after the ~latest (as of 2024-02-17) Docker Desktop for Mac update: duplicate ports in an *extended* config (e.g., if you've got `docker-compose.base.yml` and `docker-compose.local.yml` and your service `app` `extends:` from base, and *both* `app` service configs expose `3000:3000`), Docker will try to expose that port twice. That was not true previously, as far as I can tell, but it is now. Posting here for others who are encountering the same issue. The solution is to remove one of those duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, using podman :
podman machine stop && podman machine start  && podman compose up
Pros:
solve the problem
Cons:
stops all containers

I think the best solution was not stop the container. But at my case (macbook pro when closes the notebook): he stops the container and continues using the port.

Anyway: made this comment to help someone

Answer (score -1):

You may have to quit apache2 services with `sudo service apache2 stop`