# Docker: pull and run container

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I need to run `docker` container.

First things first I've pulled it with

```
docker pull [OPTIONS] NAME[:TAG|@DIGEST]
```

Next I try to run it with

```
docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE[:TAG|@DIGEST] [COMMAND] [ARG...]
```

But I get an error

```
docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint youthful_bhaskara (47fae1c2ecd6245d127801729b80276aeb3858526a9441760925d904ce1565ff): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:8888: bind: address already in use.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

With `sudo` I have a common error.

How can I fix that? 
Maybe I've missed some intermediate actions?

Comment: Are you mapping a port of the container to port 8888 of your host ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker Error bind: address already in use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37971961/docker-error-bind-address-already-in-use)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

since 8888 port is bined by another service, docker run failed to run image.
You can check which process using the port using command netstat -tunlp | grep 8888 or ps -aux | grep 8888.
To start the docker image on another port you can use -p option in docker run.
`eg: docker run -d -p 8888:8080 <image>`

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the port used, the port 8888 was already used by an other app