# Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:2049: bind: address already in use

Tags: docker, ubuntu, port, bind

On Ubuntu 18.04, I'm trying to install [Hyperledger Cello](https://github.com/hyperledger/cello), and during the install, I get:

```
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/julien/cello'
docker-compose -f bootup/docker-compose-files/docker-compose-nfs.yml up -d --no-recreate
WARNING: Found orphan containers (cello-user-dashboard, cello-operator-dashboard, cello-watchdog, cello-keycloak-server, cello-parse-server, cello-dashboard_rabbitmq, cello-mongo, cello-keycloak-mysql, cello-engine) for this project. If you removed or renamed this service in your compose file, you can run this command with the --remove-orphans flag to clean it up.
Starting cello-nfs ... error

ERROR: for cello-nfs  Cannot start service nfs: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint cello-nfs (d1be7a4999731983a12df9f1fb6484c7adf669be7edf01c6d962856ed8a6846f): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:2049: bind: address already in use

ERROR: for nfs  Cannot start service nfs: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint cello-nfs (d1be7a4999731983a12df9f1fb6484c7adf669be7edf01c6d962856ed8a6846f): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:2049: bind: address already in use
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

When trying to figure out which application is using 2049 port, I do:

```
➜  cello git:(master) ✗ sudo netstat -pna | grep 2049
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2049            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::2049                 :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2049            0.0.0.0:*                           -                   
udp6       0      0 :::2049                 :::*                                -                   
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     204951   18122/brave --type=  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     204950   5193/brave
```

But I get no app name.

I also tried to remove containers with

```
docker rm -f $(docker ps -aq)
```

like said in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37971961/docker-error-bind-address-already-in-use), but it didn't work.

How should I do to free this port ?

Comment: Port 2049 is the NFS server port.  Is your host running an NFS server? This would prevent anything else from binding on that port. The fact that your `netstat` output does not show a PID for port 2049 suggests that it is a kernel service using this port.

Comment: not that I know. I'm under ubuntu 18.04, let me check

Comment: I did the trick: sudo apt remove nfs-kernel-server ! you can put it as an answer ! Thanks !

Comment: Posted as answer. Glad to help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks as if you have an NFS server running on your host.  When you run `netstat -p ...` as root and you don't see a PID for a port, like this...

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2049            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::2049                 :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2049            0.0.0.0:*                           -                   
udp6       0      0 :::2049                 :::*                                -
```

...it generally means there is a kernel service bound to that port.  Disabling the kernel NFS server (assuming that you're not using it) should allow you to run your container.

Comment: Thank you! I was not able to use a container due to this exact reason, and it never happened to me that it could be related to a local nfs server (which it was)!

Answer (score 32):

You can try :

```
docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)
docker ps # again to make sure containers is off
sudo lsof -i tcp:2049 # now you get and list of process running and using 2049 port find and copy PID
sudo kill -9 yout_PID
```

Now that the `2049` port is killed, then try start containers again...

Comment: sudo lsof -i tcp:2049 gives me nothing

Comment: this set of commands helped me to solve my issue