# How to change PHP-FPM port on Mac

Tags: php, macos, port

I'm not using php or php-fpm, but it's hogging port 9000. I need port 9000. I'd like to change the port. I changed it in `/etc/php-fpm.conf` and `/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf`. listen = 127.0.0.1:9005. Still listening on 9000. If I kill it it just loads back up instantly with a different PID.

I'm ok uninstalling it too, but I can't figure out how to do that either. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

which php version do you have and did you install it via homebrew?

I was having this problem today and solved it by changing the configuration of the listening port:

in the config file in:
`/usr/local/etc/php/7.2/php-fpm.d/www.conf`

change the line `listen = 127.0.0.1:9000` to whatever port you want

If you don't have the config file it might have been a brew problem when copying files. You have to do something like this before attempting to change `www.conf`:

`cd $(brew --prefix php@7.2)
cp -R .bottle/* /usr/local/`

All the credits go to this blogpost: https://www.dionysopoulos.me/custom-apache-and-php-server-on-macos-the-definitive-2019-edition/

Answer (score 4):

### Update for Apple Silicon Chips

Although the current answer is correct for Mac's on Intel chips it's not correct for changing the PHP-FPM Port on Mac with Apple Silicon chips.

If following the blogpost https://www.dionysopoulos.me/custom-apache-and-php-server-on-macos-the-definitive-2019-edition/

**Do Not** copy the brew files to `/usr/local/` as this is for intel chips.
Instead, after installing php with brew, the file should already exist in:

`/opt/homebrew/etc/php/8.0/php-fpm.d/www.conf`

Or for php 5.6: `/opt/homebrew/etc/php/5.6/php-fpm.conf`

Where you can then change `listen = 127.0.0.1:9000` to the port you like.

Remember to then restart apache.

Comment: For php 8.1 the path is /opt/homebrew/etc/php/8.1/php-fpm.d/ and for php 8.2 the path is /opt/homebrew/etc/php/8.2/php-fpm.d/

Comment: `brew services restart httpd` seems not enough to make the changes effective. Also `rew services restart php` had no effect. I just killed the proceses.