# "bind: address already in use" error while using Docker Compose

Tags: docker

I am trying to install Docker in my local machine with OS Linux Mint 19.1. I am trying to use [this](https://github.com/raj039/Docker-Apache-PHP7.4-MySQL8-phpmyadmin) repo. I am following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SY_X7aKsYlY) tutorial. I am trying to run `docker-compose up` command. But I am getting below errors.

```
Creating network "docker-apache-php74-mysql8-phpmyadmin-master_default" with the default driver
Creating docker-apache-php74-mysql8-phpmyadmin-master_webserver_1 ... 
Creating png-mysql-test                                           ... 
Creating png-mysql-test                                           ... error

ERROR: for png-mysql-test  Cannot start service mysql: driver failed programming external connectivitCreating docker-apache-php74-mysql8-phpmyadmin-master_webserver_1 ... done
r starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 0.0.0.0:3306: bind: address already in use

ERROR: for mysql  Cannot start service mysql: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint png-mysql-test (08c4ea620670b02725995ea050309b2ec40432d8e89e4e4d8505d2ac959d65b7): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 0.0.0.0:3306: bind: address already in use
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

[image]

I am learning docker. How can I install & use Docker ?

Comment: Well, are you running another mysql server? It says that port 3306 is being used by something else. What's using that port?

Comment: Thanks @NickODell. Previously I installed XAMPP. May be there is another MySql server. How to know about that PORT ? What should I do in this regard ?

Comment: You can kill it off if you truly don't need it. `kill $(lsof -t -i:3306)`. If you need it, you can make use of a different port.

Comment: This thread has suggestions on how to debug this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37971961/docker-error-bind-address-already-in-use