# unable to start service in docker throwing Address already in use

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to run a service in docker below is the docker compose for that which is exposed to port as mentioned below

```yaml
saas-ac:
        image: icsdev/saas-ac
        networks:
            default:
                ipv4_address: x.xx.x.xx
        ports:
            - "18056:8000" # jpda
        hostname: "saas-ac"
        command: [ /entrypoint/entrypoint.sh, /PC/server/tomcat, catalina.out ]
        environment:
            - JPDA_ADDRESS=8000 # bind jpda port to all interfaces
            - CHEF_ENVIRONMENT=${CHEF_ENVIRONMENT}
            - CHEF_COOKBOOK_NAME=saas-ac
            - SERVICE_NAME=saas-ac
```

When I try running the service it says error

```
Cannot start service saas-ac: Address already in use
```

I checked the list of processes using various netstat and lsof commands but I didnt find any process which is using 18056 port and if I do docker ps there is no container up as well for this saas-ac name,can anyone help me in this how to solve this issue

Comment: Did you try changing the port to see if its works?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37971961/docker-error-bind-address-already-in-us)