# Spryker fails to start containers on 80 port on ubuntu

Tags: docker, spryker

Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on : Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 0.0.0.0:80: bind: address already in use

Answer (score 2):

My ubunty run apache on 80 port.
I just stop it.

```
sudo service apache2 stop
```

Also you can uninstall it as well

```
sudo apt-get purge apache2
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo rm -rf /etc/apache2
```

Comment: Also you can find recommendations here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37971961/docker-error-bind-address-already-in-use