# network mysql8 declared as external, but could not be found

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

docker create network didn't work
I tried reinstall docker, mysql too but after those, still it happens

once it worked somehow after running `prune` something and changing `docker-compose.yml`
like this

```
networks:
  mysql8:
    external: true
```

but now it doesn't work again and shows the error below

[error image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6s7z.png)

when I run `docker-compose up`, the error messages appear like this after running `docker system prune --all`

```
[+] Running 13/13
 ⠿ mysql8 Pulled                                                                               27.7s
   ⠿ f7ec5a41d630 Pull complete                                                                 7.2s
   ⠿ 9444bb562699 Pull complete                                                                 7.3s
   ⠿ 6a4207b96940 Pull complete                                                                 7.5s
   ⠿ 181cefd361ce Pull complete                                                                 7.7s
   ⠿ 8a2090759d8a Pull complete                                                                 7.8s
   ⠿ 15f235e0d7ee Pull complete                                                                 8.7s
   ⠿ d870539cd9db Pull complete                                                                 8.7s
   ⠿ 5726073179b6 Pull complete                                                                 8.8s
   ⠿ eadfac8b2520 Pull complete                                                                22.4s
   ⠿ f5936a8c3f2b Pull complete                                                                22.5s
   ⠿ cca8ee89e625 Pull complete                                                                22.5s
   ⠿ 6c79df02586a Pull complete                                                                22.6s
network mysql8 declared as external, but could not be found
```

and shows only the last message `network mysql8 declared as external, but could not be found` for `docker-compose up`

Comment: Could you post your full `docker-compose.yml`?

Comment: ` 
version: "3.1"

services:
  mysql8:
    container_name: mysql8
    image: mysql:8.0.23
    platform: linux/x86_64
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    command: mysqld --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password --lower_case_table_names=0 --transaction-isolation=READ-COMMITTED
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:**
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    networks:
      - mysql8

networks:
  mysql8:
    name: mysql8
    external: true


volumes:
  db_data:
`

why does this look so ugly hah

Comment: please put all relevant details in the question - any text such as erorr messages should be pasted as text, not as a screenshot

Comment: Do you require the manually-declared network?  Does your setup work if you delete all of the `networks:` blocks in the whole file?

Comment: @DavidMaze when I block the network part, it shows `Error response from daemon: Ports are not available: exposing port TCP 0.0.0.0:3306 -> 0.0.0.0:0: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:3306: bind: address already in use` so I killed the working pid but mysql8 doesn't get killed and appears again and again with another pid and shows the same message

Comment: [Docker Error bind: address already in use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37971961/docker-error-bind-address-already-in-use) discusses that error.  The first `3306` in your `ports:` conflicts with another MySQL server, either in a different container with a similar `ports:` line or running outside Docker entirely.  Change the port number (only the first one, the second needs to stay at `3306`), or remove the `ports:` block, or stop the other database.

Comment: (That published-ports mechanism is separate from Docker's networking subsystem; you will have the same error whatever Docker network your containers are attached to.  I'd recommend usually using the Compose-provided `default` network for simplicity.)