# 443 already in use when running docker container on raspberry pi

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, raspberry-pi, traefik

I have a raspberry pi for my home server. And I already have setup the nginx on it with ssl.

I had simple html site and my profile website running.

I just built a project with cookie-cutter-django with docker container and try to run this on my rpi, but having issue with traefik.

```
Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint new_project-traefik-1 (4759d36b8b42f426d3e20b933661d8628b23e9bfbe7c5942c9ac9e8f1e616f69):
Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 0.0.0.0:443: bind: address already in use
```

When I run `sudo netstat -pna | grep 443`, I see below.

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      22614/nginx: master 
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      22614/nginx: master
```

If I run `sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep 443`, I see below.

```
nginx     22614     root    6u  IPv4 556818      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
nginx     22614     root    7u  IPv6 556819      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
nginx     22615 www-data    6u  IPv4 556818      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
nginx     22615 www-data    7u  IPv6 556819      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
nginx     22616 www-data    6u  IPv4 556818      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
nginx     22616 www-data    7u  IPv6 556819      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
nginx     22617 www-data    6u  IPv4 556818      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
nginx     22617 www-data    7u  IPv6 556819      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
nginx     22618 www-data    6u  IPv4 556818      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
nginx     22618 www-data    7u  IPv6 556819      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
```

What I am not sure is, do I still need the traefik even though I already setup the nginx on my rpi?
If so, how do I resolve this?
I am pretty new to docker and traefik as well.
I researched a lot, but could not resolve this.

Below is my the new_project nginx sites-available setup on my rpi.

```yaml
server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/new_project.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/new_project.key;
    root /var/www/html/new_project;

    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name new_project.com *.new_project.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/new_project.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/new_project.key;

    root /var/www/html/new_project_staging;

    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name staging.new_project.com;

    location / {
       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
# force to https
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name new_project.com *.new_project.com;

    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

And the traefik setting in production.yml file in my project

```yaml
  traefik:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/traefik/Dockerfile
    image: new_project_production_traefik
    depends_on:
      - django
    volumes:
      - production_traefik:/etc/traefik/acme
    ports:
      - "0.0.0.0:80:80"
      - "0.0.0.0:443:443"
      - "0.0.0.0:5555:5555"
```

And traefik.yml file in project.

```yaml
log:
  level: INFO

entryPoints:
  web:
    # http
    address: ":80"
    http:
      # https://docs.traefik.io/routing/entrypoints/#entrypoint
      redirections:
        entryPoint:
          to: web-secure

  web-secure:
    # https
    address: ":443"

  flower:
    address: ":5555"

certificatesResolvers:
  letsencrypt:
    # https://docs.traefik.io/master/https/acme/#lets-encrypt
    acme:
      email: "admin@new_project.com"
      storage: /etc/traefik/acme/acme.json
      # https://docs.traefik.io/master/https/acme/#httpchallenge
      httpChallenge:
        entryPoint: web

http:
  routers:
    web-secure-router:
      rule: "Host(`new_project.com`) || Host(`www.new_project.com`)"
      entryPoints:
        - web-secure
      middlewares:
        - csrf
      service: django
      tls:
        # https://docs.traefik.io/master/routing/routers/#certresolver
        certResolver: letsencrypt

    flower-secure-router:
      rule: "Host(`new_project.com`)"
      entryPoints:
        - flower
      service: flower
      tls:
        # https://docs.traefik.io/master/routing/routers/#certresolver
        certResolver: letsencrypt

    web-media-router:
      rule: "(Host(`new_project.com`) || Host(`www.new_project.com`)) && PathPrefix(`/media/`)"
      entryPoints:
        - web-secure
      middlewares:
        - csrf
      service: django-media
      tls:
        certResolver: letsencrypt

  middlewares:
    csrf:
      # https://docs.traefik.io/master/middlewares/headers/#hostsproxyheaders
      # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/#ajax
      headers:
        hostsProxyHeaders: ["X-CSRFToken"]

  services:
    django:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
          - url: http://django:5000

    flower:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
          - url: http://flower:5555

    django-media:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
          - url: http://nginx:80

providers:
  # https://docs.traefik.io/master/providers/file/
  file:
    filename: /etc/traefik/traefik.yml
    watch: true
```

Lastly, nginx setup in project, not on rpi.

```yaml
server {
  listen       80;
  server_name  localhost;
  location /media/ {
    alias /usr/share/nginx/media/;
  }
}
```

cookie-cutter-django automatically create nginx setup too like above. is it really necessary to have?

Please help~!

Update, [Docker Error bind: address already in use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37971961/docker-error-bind-address-already-in-use) I had read this, but I still couldn't solve it.
the answers in above link let me check to the ports in use, and kill them. However, as you could see above, I already know it is in use with my non-container projects with the other domains.
I think it is having conflict with nginx setup on rpi with container.

what I need to figure out is... maybe... how to host multiple domains(which I already do), multiple projects that is non-container and container.
I tried to remove traefik and nginx configurations in my project, and now getting 504 error.
I guess it should be routed somehow on my rpi nginx setup. Can anybody help?

Comment: Something else on your host is already listening on the standard HTTPS port 443.  You might have two copies of your Docker project, a second Docker project also publishing port 443, or a non-container HTTP server.  The linked question describes some ways to look for the other process.  You do not need to add an additional Traefik container; if you have both Traefik and Nginx both set with `ports: ['443:...']` that would cause this problem.

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks for your quick response.
But... this question is closed by.... I don't know who... or automatically by stackoverflow.... because of similar question [Docker Error bind: address already in use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37971961/docker-error-bind-address-already-in-use). 
But as I said in "update", and as you said as well, I think it has conflict with a non-container HTTP server. 
as you suggested, I am trying to rebuild the container without traefik and nginx in the dockerized project.
hopefully it works.

Comment: @DavidMaze btw, I have not run the production yet, but just staging. and this project is the first project that I run on my rpi. so, definitely there is no other container running on same port. just the other non-container projects.