# Docker container conflicts with my centos mysql port address

Tags: docker

My docker container conflicts with my centos mysql. How do you fix that?

Error is below:
Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:3306: bind: address already in use
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

Comment: Are you running some software on the same default port in both containers (or one on the host and the other in your container)? Can you change the port on which it listens (most software allows the port to be configured)?

Comment: How are you running the container?

Comment: @Famous run your container on a different port as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41637013/docker-mysql-on-different-port

Comment: MySQL is running off of centos on port 3306. And docker is running on the server off of 3306. It’s a conflict. Which is the best practice to fix?

Answer (score 0):

May be you can see this issue:
[Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp0.0.0.0:3306: bind: address already in use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37896369/error-starting-userland-proxy-listen-tcp0-0-0-03306-bind-address-already-in)
.

Answer (score -1):

Either stop your MySQL service or map another port to your container.