# ERROR: for xxx_postgres_1 Cannot start service postgres: b'driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint dataimobi-engine_postgres_

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

Practicing the docker with rails I came across this error it says that the network is already being used, but I already restarted the docker and it did not come back

If anyone can help me thank you

```
sudo docker-compose up
dataimobi-engine_redis_1 is up-to-date
Starting dataimobi-engine_postgres_1 ... error
```

> ERROR: for dataimobi-engine_postgres_1  Cannot start service postgres: b'driver 
>   failed programming external connectivity on endpoint dataimobi-engine_postgres_1 (71c4198472ce305966f01574be2976c3fa0ccbfbfb8e0c4cf85ec9d17a30bb9d): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:5432: bind: address already in use'
>
> ERROR: for postgres  Cannot start service postgres: b'driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint dataimobi-engine_postgres_1 (71c4198472ce305966f01574be2976c3fa0ccbfbfb8e0c4cf85ec9d17a30bb9d): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:5432: bind: address already in use'
>   ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp0.0.0.0:3306: bind: address already in use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37896369/error-starting-userland-proxy-listen-tcp0-0-0-03306-bind-address-already-in)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I solved by stoping the local postgresql, and disabling it.

```
sudo service postgresql stop

sudo update-rc.d postgresql disable
```

Answer (score 3):

For me just stopping the postgresql worked

```
  sudo service postgresql stop
```